Could a React compiler compile down to native JS?
I've read a bit about Svelte - if I understand correctly, source code compiles down to native js. This is unlike React where the state management logic is the same for dev / production (i.e. there is a React import in production).
But now that there is a React compiler / will be a React compiler, what is the likelihood that React source code can be compiled down to native js?
Is there any reason that this COULDN'T be done? If it could, then it would seem to me that Svelte would not have any particular advantage over React except for preference in coding style.

What do you mean? React JSX/TSX files do get transpiled down to JS. How do you think it runs in browsers? How do you define "native JS"?

"compiling down to native JS" is very hard to define. Even tools like webpack insert a lot of JS code into the binaries they compile, but is generally not considered a library. On the other hand even librarires may modify the code via techniques like tree shaking.

React is still imported in production mode, and the render function is still the entry point. I am wondering if it is likely that the virtual dom is compiled away to direct DOM bindings.

Of course everything will compile to "native JS" eventually. It's just a matter of the sliding scale of how much library code will be in the bundle. No library can compile down to exactly 0.

Or, at least, i understand this is what Svelte does? Why not React too is the question

Okay. so what would be the limits on that sliding scale for React compared to other frameworks?

You might find this paper interesting: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.04188

Thanks - yes. that is definitely related and i'll see if i can find an answer there

Note that the DOM is not part of Native JS. The DOM is something the web browser adds to the environment the JavaScript code there is executed in (for example, the DOM is not available in JS code executed by Node.js). So Svelte code does not compile to native JS, but to JS + DOM code.

I might be wrong here, but I think it has been like this:
In all client-side rendering frameworks we have had, one typically split everything into two parts:

the state (the data that should be visualized on the screen (using numbers, strings, objects, arrays, etc. in JS))
the GUI (that describes how the state should be visualized (using HTML, CSS and some template language))

The firsts of these that we got (many, many years ago) were implemented in a really simple way: when the state changes, re-render everything. That basically means throw out all content of the old DOM, and create and insert all new content into the DOM. Very easy to implement, but each time something small changed (like a number changing from 5 to 6), the entire DOM needed to be re-rendered, so it's not implemented in a very efficient way, and big webpages would contain an noticeable amount of lag each time a re-rendering took place.
So many frameworks started to use a virtual DOM instead: the rendered GUI created a virtual DOM, and then the framework compared the virtual DOM with the actual DOM, and where it differed, it told the web browser to update those DOM parts. So the web browser needed to spend less time on updating the DOM, so that run a bit quicker. Comparing a virtual DOM with the actual DOM is a new performance cost introduced, but overall it ran quicker, so it was a better solution even though that extra cost.
Then Svelte tried to optimize it a bit further by avoiding having to create a virtual DOM, and at compile time figure out which parts of the DOM that needed to be updated when different events take place. This is much harder to do, but can lead to faster rendering times.
So, regarding the new React Compiler:

What does the compiler do?
In order to optimize applications, React Compiler automatically memoizes your code. You may be familiar today with memoization through APIs such as useMemo, useCallback, and React.memo. With these APIs you can tell React that certain parts of your application don’t need to recompute if their inputs haven’t changed, reducing work on updates. While powerful, it’s easy to forget to apply memoization or apply them incorrectly. This can lead to inefficient updates as React has to check parts of your UI that don’t have any meaningful changes.

I.e., the compiler just seems to do some optimizations programmers might have forgotten to do/won't need to do manually in the future.
So, based on that, it seems like React will still generate a virtual DOM, so the main distinction between Svelte and other virtual DOM frameworks is still there.

Side note: Svelte 5 changes the reactivity from compile time static analysis to using signals at runtime. I.e. Svelte now also has a larger runtime which is imported by all components. The base bundle size for a single component is larger but it scales better as the code for the individual components (i.e. not counting the import) is smaller.
